# Error Treeview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, treeview

Help me!
What's wrong with this code
error in TreeNode ParentNode = new TreeNode(children);

```
public partial class ViewTree : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String[] nodeStr = { "Puasa", "Puasa Sunah", "Ramadhan", "Puasa Kamis", "Puasa Senin" };
        List<TreeNode> childs = new List<TreeNode>();
        foreach (String s in nodeStr)
        {
            childs.Add(new TreeNode(s));
        }
        TreeNode[] children = childs.ToArray();
        TreeNode ParentNode = new TreeNode(children);
        TreeViewMenu.Nodes.Add(ParentNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific error it displays?

Comment: cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode[]' to 'string'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `TreeNode` constructor doesn't have `TreeNode[]` parameter, so i suppose you got complication error as you are trying to use functionality that doesn't exist. If you want to specify children for that node you need to do:

```
String[] nodeStr = { "Puasa", "Puasa Sunah", "Ramadhan", "Puasa Kamis", "Puasa Senin" };
TreeNode ParentNode = new TreeNode();
foreach (String s in nodeStr)
{
    TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(s);
    // sample of adding child nodes
    string[] valuee = new string[] { "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", "cccccccccccccccccc", "dddddddddddddddddd", "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" }; 

    foreach(string c in valuee)
    {
        childNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(c));
    }

    ParentNode.ChildNodes.Add(childNode);
}
TreeViewMenu.Nodes.Add(ParentNode);
```

**UPDATE**

I added sample that adds the same values to each child in parent node

**UPDATE2**

Here is a sample how to add items in runtime after user will click on Expand node.

ASPX content:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:TreeView ID="TreeViewMenu" runat="server" OnTreeNodePopulate="TreeViewMenu_OnTreeNodePopulate" ExpandDepth="1">

</asp:TreeView>
```

CS content:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            String[] nodeStr = { "Puasa", "Puasa Sunah", "Ramadhan", "Puasa Kamis", "Puasa Senin" };
            TreeNode ParentNode = new TreeNode();
            foreach (String s in nodeStr)
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(s);
                node.PopulateOnDemand = true;
                ParentNode.ChildNodes.Add(node);
            }
            TreeViewMenu.Nodes.Add(ParentNode);
        }
    }

    protected void TreeViewMenu_OnTreeNodePopulate(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] value = new string[] { "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", "cccccccccccccccccc", "dddddddddddddddddd", "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" };

        foreach (var v in value)
        {
            e.Node.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(v));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: then how to enter values into the node, for example with these values:
string[] valuee = new string[]
{
     "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
     "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
     "cccccccccccccccccc",
     "dddddddddddddddddd",
     "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
};

Comment: It follows the same logic. I updated answer with sample that will add that values to each child for parent node. So you can add them in such way.

Comment: without at the click then the value will appear as childnode.

mean when I click on "puasa" node to perform "aaaaaa"
"puasa sunah" nodes appear "bbbbb" and so on, ..

Comment: If you want to do it on click, then you need to subscribe to `TreeNodePopulate`\`TreeNodeExpanded` events and do that code there (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodepopulate(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodeexpanded(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: please help me update the code above, I do not understand the language in which you show a web page

Comment: i've added another sample with handling node clicking

Comment: sorry I mean not like it, but like in carrot2.org, can be seen here http://search.carrot2.org/stable/search?source=web&view=folders&skin=fancy-compact&query=bandung&results=100&algorithm=lingo&EToolsDocumentSource.country=ALL&EToolsDocumentSource.language=ALL&EToolsDocumentSource.customerId=&EToolsDocumentSource.safeSearch=false# when you click on one of the nodes it will show its contents